# How to use ngResource-like query urls with $http

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I'm using Angular and I've got to do some not-restful ajax calls. And, because of that I can't use `ngResource`. My URL are something like `/admin/:someId` or `/admin/:someId/users/:someUserId`.

The ngResource methods just parse those tokens but, is there some way to use those URLs with the `$http` object?

I'm exposing my backend routes to javascript in the following manner: `/slug/:param1/slug/:param2`.
With the `ngResource` methods I have to do the following to get it working: `Resource.query({param1: someValue, param2: anotherValue});`. 
The problem is that I cannot use `ngResource` in this case and I am not able to get it working with the `$http.get` method, it does not replace the tokens `:param1` and `:param2` for the values. It just calls to `/slug/:param1/slug/:param2`.

Comment: Can you  be a bit more specific about what you want to do? You can call definitely $http's shorthand methods, such as $http.get(), $http.post(), $http.put etc.. which returns a promise that allows you to chain it to the then() method. Those URL looks fine to me, it just means there is a bit more processing to do with those extra parameters. You can probably pair them with  $routeParams to get those tokens.

Comment: The problem is that $http does not replace the parameter tokens with the values, I edited my first post.

Comment: So can you not use $routeParams.param1 and $routeParams.param2 and put it inside $http.get("/slug/" + $routeParams.param1 + "/slug/" + $routeParams.param2).then(cb).catch(err); perhaps I've misunderstood something.

Comment: No, I'm exposing my URLs from the server like `/slug/:param1/slug/:param2` as **javascript String variables**. This way I don't have to do messy concatenation stuff. I know that if the `ngResource` methods autamatically replace the query tokens there has to be a way to do that using the same service Angular does use, but I can't seem to find any information about this.

Comment: Maybe you should revisit using the `$resource` ... `$http` definitely does not do the thing w/parameters. What were the actual problems you had when using `$resource`?

Comment: I'm just not doing rest requests. So I think is not possible to use the `ngResource`. I need to send 2 lists to the server to update both. Those lists depend in a `:departmentId` that is on the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone finds this thread, I ended doing this:

```
.factory('RouteUtils', function () {
return {
    /**
     * Replaces all token appearances with their corresponding value.
     * 
     * @param string route The route that has the tokens you want to replace. Tokens must be like ":someString".
     * @param object params Object of parameters. It must be key value. For example: {firstKey: 34, secondKey: 'I'm some string'}.
     * 
     * @returns string Token replaced route.
     */
    parse: function (route, params) {
        var propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(params);
        propNames.forEach(function (propName) {
            route = route.replace(':' + propName, encodeURI(params[propName]))
        });

        return route;
    }
};
```

})

Then on the `$http` call:

```
.factory('SomeFactory', function ($http, RouteUtils) {
    return {
        someGetCall: function (params) {
            return $http.get(RouteUtils.parse(routeGet, params));
        },
        somePostCall: function (params) {
            return $http.post(RouteUtils.parse(routePost, params), {
                postParam1: 'postValue1',
                postParam2: 'postValue2'
            });
        },
    };
})
```

Being the variable *route* something like `/user/:userId/games/:gameId/` and *params* something like `{userId: 34, gameId: 55}` the **parse** method would return `/user/34/games/55/`

It's the best solution I could think of since I wasn't able to find a native Angular way to do it.